# How to skin an mx:DateChooser in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, datechooser

I found these properties:

```
selectionIndicatorSkin="..."
todayIndicatorSkin="..."
```

Which skins the DateChooser Selected and todays item.

Oddly enough I didn't find a way where I can specifiy the skin for regular days! I found this property:

```
weekDayStyleName="..."
```

so I created a style

```
.myStyle{
    skin-class: ClassReference("com.mySkin");
}
```

then used it: weekDayStyleName="myStyle" But it didn't work! Any ideas?

Extra Code:

```
<mx:DateChooser id="date1" 
                todayStyleName="myTodayStyle"
                headerStyleName="myHeaderStyle"
                selectionIndicatorSkin="com.skins.calendar.SelectionIndicatorSkin"
                todayIndicatorSkin="com.skins.calendar.TodayIndicatorSkin1"
                focusSkin="com.skins.calendar.TodayIndicatorSkin1"
                rollOverIndicatorSkin="com.skins.calendar.SelectionIndicatorSkin"
                weekDayStyleName="weekdayStyle"
                borderColor="#FFFFFF"
                todayColor="#FFFFFF"
                width="275" height="275" />

<fx:Style >
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace vld "com.lal.validators.*";
    @namespace effect "com.lal.effects.*";
    @namespace components "com.lal.components.*";



    .weekdayStyle{
        skin-class: ClassReference("com.lal.skins.calendar.TodayIndicatorSkin1");
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 18;
    }
</fx:Style>
```

Comment: I was wondering what do you want to style/skin? something related to the font?

Comment: No it's actually teh Calendar that shows with DateChooser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that all the days in a DateChooser class are [UITextFields](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UITextField.html).

UITextFields do not have a style named skin-class.  Check out all [styles for the UITextField class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UITextField.html#top).

As such, your style is probably ignored.

Many Flex 4 Spark components have a style named skinClass which you use to set the skin class of the component, but I didn't think such a thing existed for MX Components.

You should be able to customize the look and feel of days by creating your own custom class that implements the IUITextField and then set that as a style with the textFieldClass style.

Comment: I'm surprised that it's working for "Selected Day" and for "Today" so the skins apply correctly but not for the regular day.

Comment: Can you show us the full code and/or a link to a running sample?

Comment: Thanks Flextras I added extra with the questions please check it out. the skins I added with selectionIndicatorSkin and todayIndicatorSkin work fine. I just don't seem to be able to skin regular non selected days.

Comment: Based on your code, I'm going to reiterate my original answer about the "skin-class" style name.  You said that same style is working on selectionIndicatorSkin and todayIndicatorSkin, but you setting those styles in a very different way.